# I want to print the rgb values of frames of a video in python

Tags: python, video, rgb, infinite-loop, steganography

I want to print the RGB values of frames of a video in python. I tried writing a code in python but the for loop where we print the newframe goes into an infinite loop. Guide me on how shall I overcome this, as an output it should print the RGB value of each pixel. I have attached the code below.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

count=0
def messageToBinary(message):
  if type(message) == str:
    return ''.join([ format(ord(i), "08b") for i in message ])
  elif type(message) == bytes or type(message) == np.ndarray:
    return [ format(i, "08b") for i in message ]
  elif type(message) == int or type(message) == np.uint8:
    return format(message, "08b")
  else:
    raise TypeError("Input type not supported")



vidcap = cv.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
if not vidcap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = vidcap.read()
     # -------------------------------------------------------------> step 2 - split
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    width, height, d= frame.shape
    print("reshaped...")
    row=int(width*height)
    newframe = frame.reshape(row,3)

    # print(newframe)
    # print(newframe[i][j])
    #the loop below is going into infinite looping  
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(0,3):
                print(newframe[i][j])


    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break


# When everything is done, release the capture

vidcap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: At lease use `i` and `j`. `for i in range(height):` and `for j in range(width):` and `for k in range(3):` and `print(newframe[i, j, k])`. Test the loop with one image (not a video). Use a very small image with known RGB values.

Comment: It doesn't go in an infinite loop, it just prints the first pixel [0][0] at each iteration, when you want to do [i][j] instead.

Comment: @Reti43 it does the same if I write [i][j]

Comment: Yes, @Rotem I am trying to test the loop with an image. Will give the updates

Comment: You need to explicitly say what "the same" means. You have an infinite loop where you read frames from the camera, but for each frame, you iterate a finite number of pixels and print them. If they're all black, for example, it will look like it's doing the same with each print, but it doesnt. If the image has only one pixel, for each (infinite) camera frame loop, you print that one pixel and that may look like an infinite process. What data does `newframe` hold? What does `print(frame.shape)` say, what does `print(newframe)` say? When you iterate the pixels, `print(i, j, newframe[i][j])`.

Comment: I tried printing the individual RGB values by converting the numpy array to a 2d list and then iterating it. When I run the code and print the values, it seems like it will take forever to print the RGB values. Maybe it isn't an infinite loop and just a lot of values to print. `newframe` is a numpy array holding RGB values of a video frame. @Reti43

Comment: Printing is a very slow process. Accessing 1000 pixels can be done almost instantaneously, but if you were to print them, it'd take a couple of seconds. For an image with almost a million pixels, that will take significantly longer. But if you need it works, you don't need to print anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm understanding now. Is it possible to connect with you on LinkedIn as I learn you have a good knowledge of steganography? @Reti43